# How to get Rust code coverage staticstics in Clion 2021.1

Tags: rust, code-coverage, clion

It looks like CLion 2021.1 has source-based code coverage working with the Rust plugin because I can see the green/red line annotations in the code view:

[image: example annotations]

But if I go to the `Coverage` panel, I see the following:

[image]

Clicking the `Edit` button does not guide me in how to fix configuration settings.

#### Summary

I'd like to be able to view Rust code coverage statistics with CLion 2021.1, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps, they fixed it for me:

1. Close CLion and delete the folder `.idea` in the project directory (yes, really)
2. Update `grcov` by running `cargo install --force grcov`
3. Start CLion and try it again